# Using Google Earth Engine to exclude upper 1% of data?

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter

I would like to exclude the upper 1% of my Data ('VV' Band) because of noise reduction

```
var s1_data = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')

var s1_grd_iw_vv_des = s1_data
  .filterDate(begin,end)
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('relativeOrbitNumber_stop',orbnr))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('sliceNumber',slinr))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq("orbitProperties_pass", "DESCENDING"))
  .sort('system:time_start');
```

I guess i have to write a function like

```
var upper_percent = function(image) {
   var one_percent = ????
   var maskedImage = image.mask().and(one_percent.not());
   return image.updateMask(maskedImage);}
```

I dont know the command to call? Is there a pre-defined one?

**EDIT:**
I try this

```
var filter2 = function(image) {
  var nn = image.select('VV').reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([99]));
  var out = image.select('VV').gt(nn.select('p99');
  var maskedImage = image.mask().and(out.not());
  return image.updateMask(maskedImage);}
```

but if i look up the histogram there were no pixel excluded (masked). Dont matter if i try 99, or 90 or even 50 ?

Comment: Possibly an `ee.Reducer.percentile()` could be used for this purpose.

Comment: This code is not runnable since `begin`, `end`, `orbnr`, `slinr` are undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be something like this:

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([-121.17167968749999, 38.190443614671594]);
var s1_data = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')

var s1_grd_iw_vv_des = s1_data
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq("orbitProperties_pass", "DESCENDING"))
  .sort('system:time_start')
  .select('VV');

print(s1_grd_iw_vv_des)

var withPercentiles = s1_grd_iw_vv_des.map(function(image) {
  return image.set(image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.percentile([99]), 
    geometry: image.geometry().bounds(), 
    scale: image.projection().nominalScale(), 
    bestEffort: true
  }));
});
print(withPercentiles.first())

var masked = withPercentiles.map(function(image) {
  var mask = image.lt(ee.Image.constant(image.get('VV')));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
})

var check = ee.Image(masked.first());
Map.centerObject(check, 8)
Map.addLayer(check, {min: -25, max: 0}, 'check')
```

Comment: Great thanks.... only `scale: image.projection().nominalScale()` throws _Error generating chart: reduce.max: Error in map(ID=S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20170108T054217_20170108T054242_014736_017FCE_EE6B):
Image.projection: The bands of the specified image contains different projections. Use Image.select to pick a single band._ But when i say `scale:100` its no problem

Comment: Then pick an appropriate scale or pick a band to use.

Answer (score 0):

I try it with this function 
// Mean and Standart Derivation

```
var remove_percent = function(image) {
  var sd = image.reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev()) //Standart Deviation
  var mean = image.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()) //Mean
  var e1 = ee.Image()
  var e2 = ee.Image()
  var b1 = e1.expression('mean - 1.96 * stD', {'mean':mean, 'stD': sd}) //Border between 1% and 0%
  var b2 = e2.expression('mean + 1.96 * stD', {'mean':mean, 'stD': sd}) //Border between 99% and 100%
  var edge = image.gt(b2) 
  image.addBands(edge)
  var maskedImage = image.mask().and(edge.not())
  return image.updateMask(maskedImage) }
```

Now it removes "something" but not the wanted 1 upper % ;) i dont get it

EDIT:
Maybe the Problem is that the original VV band has only negative values? If i calculate the mean seperatly it is positive.